# Can't run GitKraken on ParrotOS 4.3

Tags: debian, gitkraken, libcrypto, parrot-os

I've downloaded and installed GitKraken twice(the latter after uninstalling the previous installation, upgrading all the system and rebooting)the .deb file both via firefox and via wget and ran it as well via dpkg -i and GDebi...
Still, when I try to run it, all I get is:

```
#gitkraken
Node started time: 1541778888367
libcrypto.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error: libcrypto.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
at process.module.(anonymous function) [as dlopen] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:166:20)
at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:671:18)
at Object.module.(anonymous function) [as .node] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:180:18)
at Module.load (module.js:561:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:504:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:496:3)
at Module.require (module.js:586:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar/node_modules/nodegit/dist/nodegit.js:12:12)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar/node_modules/nodegit/dist/nodegit.js:1145:3)
```

and the cursor that keeps blinking...

Any idea or suggestion?
Thank you very much for your help!

PS: I've also tried to install `libcrypto`, yet all the terminal returns me is:

```
$sudo apt-get install libssl1.0.0 libssl-dev --reinstall
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libssl1.0.0 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libssl1.0.0' has no installation candidate
```

Or even:

```
$sudo apt-get install libcrypto
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libcrypto
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to install package "libgnome-keyring0"